# Cygwin home directory

Tags: windows, cygwin, zsh, conemu

i'm using cygwin with conemu and zsh

> "C:\cygwin64\bin\zsh.exe --login -i"

and in my /etc/nsswitch.conf I set (using passwd file makes no difference)

```
db_home: windows
db_passwd: windows
```

My HOME env variable now points at

> /cygdrive/c/Users/username

which is the correct folder.

But my problem appears on installing oh-my-zsh (for example)
It creates a folder "C:\cygdrive\c\Users\username\.oh-my-zsh" instead of "C:\Users\username\.oh-my-zsh".

Does someone know what's the problem?

Comment: I do not see difference in the two directories you mention `/cygdrive/c/Users/ebender` . Can you clarify what you expect ?

Comment: Open an issue upstream https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues